# Mongoose: Query by subdocument ObjectId attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query:

```
Stuff.findOneAndUpdate({ status: 'open', ...query }, value, { new: true });
```

where `query` is: `{ 'buyer.user': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id) }`;

As you can see, my `Stuff` model has a subdocument `buyer`, that has a `user` attribute with an `ObjectId`

If I run that exact query in mongo directly it returns the result I want but, it always returns empty when using mongoose.

Do you have any ideas why?

**Edit**

This is my schema:

```
const StuffSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    items: [{ type: Donation.schema, default: [] }],
    status: { type: String, default: 'open', enum: ['open', 'purchase_completed'] },
    total: Number,
    buyer: { type: BuyerDataSchema },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

and

```
const BuyerDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: false },
    email: { type: String, required: false },
    phone: { type: String, default: '' },

    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
  { _id: false }
);
```

Does this help?

Comment: Add the schema please.

Comment: @Ayzrian schemas added

Comment: `buyer: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: BuyerDataSchema}`. Just like how you ref `user` in your `buyer` shcema

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a `ref` and want to include that subdocument into a result of query you need to call `populate` functuon with the name of a field e.g.

```
   Stuff.find(...).populate("user")
```